# Javascript function: use newlines as \n instead of actually rendering them

Tags: javascript, newline

I am working on a function that receives text from a textarea input with an aim of retaining newline characters. The function then takes the text as an argument to the function, for example: `function get_text(val){ ... }`.
The value being received from the textarea is:

```
$('#textarea').val();
```

Such that on the click of a button, the value in the textarea is passed to the `get_text()` function, for example:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    get_text($('#textarea').val());
});
```

Then the function is meant to use the newline characters which are retained since the value is from a textarea.
But here is where the problem comes in, when I pass the value of the textarea to the `get_text()` function, I get an error in the console stating: **Unexpected identifier** because the argument has been split over a few lines, for example:

If the text in the input is:
(Line 1)**My**
(Line 2)**text**
(Line 3)**is**
(Line 4)**here**

The function takes the text and outputs the newline characters:

```
get_text("My   --- (×)Error appears here
text
is
here");
```

I'm trying to use the newline characters from the textarea in the function which performs some task after every newline character is encountered, so getting rid of the newlines is not an option unless there is another way to perform the task.

The only problem here is actually passing the text into the function, for example:

```
get_text($('#textarea').val());
--- should result to ---
get_text('My\ntext\nis\nhere');
--- instead of actually outputting the newlines ---
```

Which works well with the function.
Is there a way to pass the text to the function without printing the newlines but instead show them as \n ?

This is the get_text function:

```
function get_text(val){
let n = /[\n]/;
let i;
let inner = [];
for(i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
inner.push('<span>' + val[i] + '</span>';
if(n.test(val[i]) == true){
inner.push('<span class="newline">' + val[i] + '</span>';
}
}
return inner.join("");
}
```

And again, the problem is not even in the function, it is only when the value is passed to the function, it gets split into lines ... and no, I am not using `eval`

Yes I get the error only after getting it from a form

[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having newlines in a string... Are you using `eval()` to run this...?

Comment: show your `get_text` function. You should not be getting an error in the param

Comment: Use backticks \` for template string syntax

Comment: your code has syntax errors.  it's not the string parametter that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace them with the backslash (`\`) and `n` characters literally.

To create a `\` in a literal, escape it with itself, i.e. `\\`.

So,

```js
$('#textarea').val().replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
```

Comment: So I've tried this, and works like a charm, the function on the second page gets the value with the actual **\n** characters as part of the string: "My\ntext\nis\nhere" ... But from within the same page, this function is actually not needed because it still works anyway - **√** This works when submitting the value via a form because it puts the actual '\n' characters in the text and that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

[MDN Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Template literal syntax allows your string to span multiple lines using the ` backticks as the container, which should avoid your problem.  I would still recommend escaping the string and/or not mixing the server-side templating code and JavaScript code like that, especially not embedding form data as JS code verbatim.  You can at least serialize it with `json_encode` or something similar.

You could also use `JSON.stringify` of the form data, and then `JSON.parse` it afterwards.

```js
let val = `My
test
is
here`;

get_text(`My
text
is
here`);
```

You're missing parens and you're not using `.test` right.  It takes the string, not a boolean comparison, and returns a boolean if it matches.
Also, if you want line breaks you should be using `<br>`.  Putting a newline in a `<span>` will  just collapse.  It will not insert a line break in the rendered output.  Unless you're using some CSS style like a float break that does the line break for you.

```js
function get_text(val) {
  let n = /[\n]/;
  let i;
  let inner = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    inner.push('<span>' + val[i] + '</span>');
    if (n.test(val[i])) {
      inner.push('<span class="newline">' + val[i] + '</span>');
    }
  }
  return inner.join("");
}

console.log(
  content.innerHTML = get_text(`My
text
is
here`)
)
```

```css
.newline::after {
  content: '\\n'
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: I've noted the syntax errors, and the function works well when I'm within the same page, so now when I use it in a form and submit the value then capture it, in this case I'm using `django` to capture the value: `{{myvalue}}` This is the place where it gets split into lines: The value that is supposed to be passed is: `let val = {{myvalue}}` ... and this is the place where it gets split [It only happens after when retrieving it from a form]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly.  But is this what you mean?  I've created a CSS style that inserts "\\n" if it sees the class "newline"?

Comment: Oh, I see.  Server side template engine is being used to insert JavaScript variables with line breaks?  Is that what's happening?  I suppose you could use backticks?  Although I think it would be wise to be escaping those variables anyways and not allow things like line breaks happen.  Or just keep them separate.

Comment: Yes, view the screenshot in the edited question, Also tried getting it with php but same case

Comment: Use the backticks for template literals.  I gave an example at the top of my answer.  I still recommend that you either escape the strings and not intermix the server side template engine generated stuff and the JavaScript stuff like that, especially verbatim from a form.

Comment: Or use JSON.stringify of your form data so you serialize it, and use JSON.parse back on the client side

Comment: I've tried JSON.stringify then parse it on the other page but for some reason I get an error: Invalid & character because when the value is stringified into JSON it adds quotes so this is the value received on the other page: "&quot;My text is here&quot;" ... But your suggestion of escaping the newline strings which @FZs has also mentioned above works because it adds the newline characters as part of the submitted string, thanks